# How to use EvenQ[] in patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching

This works:

```
(w[1] + w[2] + w[3]) /. w[s_] -> If[s == 2, w[s], 0]

(* w[2] *)
```

This doesn't:

```
(w[1] + w[2] + w[3]) /. w[s_] -> If[EvenQ[s], w[s], 0]

(* 0 *)
```

Why?

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one does not work as intended because `EvenQ[x]` always returns `False` if `x` is not "manifestly an even integer" (quote from docs.) Since you use `->` instead of `:>`, the expression `If[EvenQ[s], w[s], 0]` is evaluated at once, and since `s` is a symbol at that stage, it is not manifestly an even integer. The first example works because `s == 2` is neither `True` nor `False` until `s` aquires a value, which happens after replacement. The second one works with `RuleDelayed`:

```
(w[1] + w[2] + w[3]) /. w[s_] :> If[EvenQ[s], w[s], 0]
(* w[2] *)
```

Comment: @Jerry, it might help you to look at the analogy between the pairs `=`/`:=` and `->`/`:>`; the ones on the left evaluate their right-hand sides at once, and the right ones don't. In your case, the instant evaluation resulted in an `If[False, (* stuff *)]`.

Comment: @J. M.  I understand the instant vs. delayed evaluation thing now, but I still don't understand why this wasn't a problem for "s==2".  Why doesn't that return False upon instant evaluation?

Comment: @Jerry, `Equal` does not evaluate at once unless both sides are numeric or manifestly equal, which is why it is useful for representing *equations* (e.g. in `Solve[]` and `ContourPlot[]`).

Comment: @J. M. So then, what is the purpose of "->"?  Is it ever preferable to ":>"?  Should we just use ":>" all the time?

Comment: If you have a fixed rule that you apply to a lot of expressions, it's wasteful to use the delayed one, because it evaluates each time. There are uses for both, just like there are uses for both `=` and `:=`.